# Making struct conform to Identifiable crashes app

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-monterey

**EDITS:**

- removed `id: \.self`
- removed `.onDelete` from `List` (mistake in editing)
- removed `removeRows` function
- change the `Note` struct to only hash the `id`

I am making an app in swiftUI that returns a list of notes. I have a struct, `note`, that is defined as follows:

```swift
struct Note: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var content: String

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

It conforms to `Identifiable` so that it can be selected inside a `List`, and it conforms to `Hashable` so that it can be held inside a `Set` (for selection).

My view that (I think) is being super slow and eventually crashing is as follows:

```swift
struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var searchValue: String = ""
    @State private var searchResults: [Note] = [
        Note(title: "Hi", content: "whats up"),
        Note(title: "wassup", content: "hi")
    ]
    @State private var selectKeeper = Set<Note>()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            SearchInputView(searchValue: $searchValue, searchResults: $searchResults)
            
            List(searchResults, selection: $selectKeeper) { note in
                Text(note.title )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`SearchInputView` is basically just a view that uses combine to run this function on the contents of a textfield every keypress:

```
func findIn(notes: [Note], pattern: String) -> [Note] {
    if pattern.isEmpty { return notes }
    
    var matchedNotes: [Note] = []
    
    for note in notes {
        let note = Note(title: note.title.uppercased(), content: note.content.uppercased())
        let pattern = pattern.uppercased()
        if note.title.contains(pattern) || note.content.contains(pattern) {
            matchedNotes.append(note)
        }
    }
    
    return matchedNotes
}
```

This all used to work fine with a `ForEach` loop and the `Note` struct not conforming to `Identifiable`, but right now for whatever reason, the app crashes as soon as I type anything into the text box. I have no idea why this is happening, and I can't see anything in the profilers that might tell me what's going on. The only thing is that as soon as I type *all* of the uses goes up to 100% and the app crashes. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `id: \.self` in the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: @Yrb The code compiles, but it still has the same issue. (And to be clear: you mean the `List`, right?)

Comment: Maybe unrelated but there are some bad practices: 1)`onDelete` works only in a `ForEach` expression. 2) If you have an `id` property it's worth it to implement the `combine` method to hash only the `id` value 3) `id: \.self` is pointless (and inefficient) if the item does conform to `Indentifiable`.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for pointing that out. The `onDelete` was actually not in the code I have running, I think it was in that example because I deleted most (but not all) of some commented code I have in the actual file. I have implemented the note struct to only hash the id, but the same issue is present.

Comment: Yes, I meant on the `List`. Can you post an actual [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? There is no obvious reason for it to be crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my problem was due to putting the `findIn` function outside of the struct that was using it. I am not at all sure why this is, but putting it inside of the struct calling it caused it to work out fine. Thanks so much to everyone who provided helpful suggestions in the comments!